# How to still keep your job without taking additional responsibilities at work?

Tags: software-industry, software-development, performance-reviews, developer, corporate-responsibility

I am an UI developer at a large US firm and I was hired specifically to do the UI work. During my year-end review, my boss congratulated me for my work and told me he expects that I take additional responsibilities for next year similar to product management kind of role. He also stressed that I should build a career within the firm so he wants me to come up with a plan about where I want to be in the next three years.

However, I have no interest in taking additional responsibilities at work or building a career for that matter because I am just not interested. I solely want to focus on writing UI code - that is my best interest. I consider myself a very talented in UI developer compared to my colleagues because I am a master in it and work everyday to keep the skills up in this fast changing industry.

Could I face any dire consequences for not taking additional responsibilities at my work? Or can I last long in the company? How do I tell my boss that I am simply here to do my job and fulfilled by it?

Comment: This is your opportunity to create your own road map. If you love UI, perhaps you'd like to lead the UI development for the entire company so that you can spread your passion and ideas? Or could you head up the product from a UI perspective?

Comment: How did you determine you are a master?  This is typically a title bestowed by others.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, while new users are very welcome, there's simply no point posting multiple very similar questions - just post the one good one!

Comment: yes @jio please select the question you phrased best and delete the others, as they may be redundant and confusing to users. Welcome to The Workplace :)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to check if your boss is the one who want good employees or one that want to "produce" managers.

Remember that in some companies you cannot go past certain pay if you are not promoted to certain groups or position. With that in mind embelish WHY you don't want to do certain things.

For example for me it was my inability to enforce anyone to do their job and not "problem-solve". I cannot demand from people to do their given tasks. So I would be a bad leader. But I'm pretty good at helping others. So I'm better suited for being a support. So now my job (apart from main task) is to solve problems, think about solutions and give it to others to do. With their managers as enforcers.

So that what I would say "I want to do UI in next three years". Add things like "and share the knowledge about it in company", "Because I'm very task oriented and I can organize my time I also expect that from everyone else. I cannot force people to do it because I expect them to be as driven as me".

Start from the end, in three years you want to do UI. For whom? Do you want to do it from A to Z or are there stuff you don't like doing? What are yours strong point that make you good employee now that would not translate or even get lost if you were PM.

Talk to your boss (and company) in their gains. What they gain if you do UI and what they could lost if you weren't. Make them aware that you are OK (if you are) with not getting a promotion and big pay rise. Every company need a worker ant and if the ant is happy being just that the company can draw from that.

Answer (score 0):

Your boss is telling you he wants you to become a key employer, but in order for you to become that you need to do more of the stuff he needs done.

In other words, if you do not take up the work he suggests for you he will need to hire another person to do it.  There might not be enough UI work for you to keep you fully occupied, and you do not want to do anything else so he cannot give you other kinds of work.   Therefore the boss might give up on you hire somebody who is willing to do the work he is asking of you to grow into, leaving you redundant.

So, it boils down to what you want to do in X years, and if anybody is willing to let you do that.  You might need to look for a long time to find such a place.

Comment: Is it OK for employers to give employees work that is not mentioned in the job post?

Comment: @jio Excellent question.  Have you studied the contract you signed?  Are you in an union?